# Converting Visual Basic parallel port app using inpout32.dll in to Delphi

Tags: vb.net, delphi, parallel-port

I've been given this simple VB application and library which I'm told can open a door/turnstyle attached to the printer port at 0x378 base address.

```
   'Inp and Out declarations for port I/O using inpout32.dll.

Public Declare Function Inp Lib "inpout32.dll" Alias "Inp32" _
    (ByVal PortAddress As Integer) _
    As Integer

Public Declare Sub Out Lib "inpout32.dll" Alias "Out32" _
    (ByVal PortAddress As Integer, _
    ByVal Value As Integer)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Option Explicit
Dim Value As Integer
Dim PortAddress As Integer

Private Sub cmdWriteToPort_Click()
'Write to a port.
Out PortAddress, Value
'Read back and display the result.
Text1.Text = Inp(PortAddress)
Value = Value + 1
If Value = 255 Then Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
'Test program for inpout32.dll
Value = 0
'Change PortAddress to match the port address to write to:
'(Usual parallel-port addresses are &h378, &h278, &h3BC)
PortAddress = &H378
End Sub
```

However I need to re-write it in Delphi 5 to integrate in to my application.

1. Is it possible to access the same library through D5?
2. Am I in the right direction with the following code?

//Inp and Out declarations for port I/O using library

```
function Inp(PortAddress:String); external 'inpout32.dll.dll'
begin
 return ??
end;

procedure Output(PortAddress:String;Value:Integer); external 'inpout32.dll.dll'

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
//Test program for inpout32.dll

Value := 0;

//Change PortAddress to match the port address to write to:
//(Usual parallel-port addresses are &h378, &h278, &h3BC)

PortAddress := '&H378';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

//Write to a port.
Output(PortAddress, Value);

//Read back and display the result.
Edit1.Text := Inp(PortAddress);
Value := Value + 1;

if Value = 255 then
Value := 0;

end;
```

I'm not sure exactly how to declare the library functions and what to declare the variables as (&H378 is obviously not an integer)

thanks

Comment: &H378 is a hexadecimal value: 888 in decimal. Dunno if that will fit into Delphi's integer type.

Comment: @Xopmeister Thanks. I'm guessing the library function only accepts Hexadecimal in this case but not sure. Removing the H seems to let it set the value $378 anyway...

Comment: Are you working with a serial or parallel port? The reason I ask is that one of the comments appears to discuss a parallel port.

Comment: You're right the code is actually trying to talk to the parallel port, not the serial. That is why I was getting different results on different PCs. I didn't even know parallel port was the printer port (oops)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PortAddress is declared as an Integer, so don't use strings. Your code should look something like this:

```
//Inp and Out declarations for port I/O using inpout32.dll.
function Inp(PortAddress: Integer): Integer; stdcall; external 'inpout32.dll' name 'Inp32';

procedure Output(PortAddress, Value: Integer); stdcall; external 'inpout32.dll' name 'Out32';

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Test program for inpout32.dll
  Value := 0;

  //Change PortAddress to match the port address to write to:
  //(Usual parallel-port addresses are $378, $278, $3BC)
  PortAddress := $378;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //Write to a port.
  Output(PortAddress, Value);

  //Read back and display the result.
  Edit1.Text := IntToStr(Inp(PortAddress));
  Value := Value + 1;

  if Value = 255 then
    Value := 0;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks clearly I forgot to state what was being return by the function. However this code gives the error "Identifier expected but 'function' found after the Type". If I removed Type it compiles OK but displays 0 in the edit box and increments on each click, where as the original program displayed 255 everytime. Any ideas?

Comment: @notidaho "if Value = 255 then Value := 0;" <-- I suspect this makes the "Value" variable change to ZERO in stead of showing "255" like in the original program.

Comment: Well yea. But in the OP the original VB code is doing that too yet it doesn't get reset to 0 so that's what confusing me.

Comment: @notidaho: indeed, the **type** keyword shouldn't be used there.

Comment: @notidaho: that is probably because FormActivate event is fired and thus Value is reset to 0. If you want to initialize Value and PortAddress only once, use the FormCreate event instead of FormActivate.

Comment: @The_Fox Very good spot. I've changed it to FormCreate but no difference so maybe it's just not grabbing that value. I could do with a way to test if the port is actually outputting...

Comment: @notidaho: Maybe its the original program that was wrong? Is the value you read from the serial port always meant to be 255? Or an echo of the value you just outputted to the serialport?

Comment: @The_Fox You're sort of correct. I was running the original program on a PC which does not have a parallel port and for whatever reason that meant it responded with 255. Both programs behave the same when on the same PC though so essentially this thread is answered. Thanks alot :)

Comment: @notidaho: That 255 decimal (FF hex) value is the expected value for "there is nothing at this address".  A long time ago, in DOS you could directly access hardware at its "base address" which was the address where it mapped to using the ISA expansion cards. To keep that capacity in a modern operating system, you are using a device driver and a DLL that give you access to those IO addresses. Printer ports were usually an expansion card with jumper switches to set the base address on the ISA bus.  $378 is the default address of LPT1 on an original IBM PC.

Answer (score 1):

You should completely drop using **inpout32.dll** since it's only used to directly access printer port and complicates your code conversion. You can do the same much more efficient with [**ZLOPRTIO**](http://www.torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=ZLPORTIO+&Title=Yes) Delphi library.

Comment: I'm actually just in the process of ONLY loading this .dll when the user actually needs it and I'm hoping to replace it with a USB version in the next version anyway. Thanks for the advice though