# VB.net and GPIO

Tags: vb.net, gpio

I need to open a cash drawer connected to a computer's RJ-11 Port. The manual said about the RJ11 connector `case open: GPIO 63 ADD A25H(bit3)`

How can I access to that GPIO from VB.Net? Anybody has an example?

Comment: There has got to be more information in the docos than that.  I have to assume you will be using the SerialPort class, unless there in an included SDK that offers a higher level of abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Google I figured out that you are probably using a Biostar embedded PC motherboard

[Manual](http://www.biostar-europe.com/v4/upload/PC_Manual/BIPV10-IAP_110425.pdf)

and the table you are referencing is :

[image: RJ-11 Table]

This would seem to indicate that the value you are talking about is a *STATUS* pin - an input, not an output.  The cash drawer would indicate to the PC the state of the drawer (open or closed) using this line.  You would read this bit, not write to it, to learn the status of the drawer.

The GPIO is just memory mapped I/O.  You would need to use a low level memory read at memory address 0xA25 to retrieve this word.  Presumably writing to the *CONTROL* pins would cause the drawer to open.  Without a better manual for your device it is difficult to say.

I don't think .NET provides any means to write to memory mapped IO but you may be able to do it by importing system .dll functions with code like this :

[Converting Visual Basic parallel port app using inpout32.dll in to Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240520/converting-visual-basic-parallel-port-app-using-inpout32-dll-in-to-delphi)

but replacing the Parallel Port address with the ones you are interested in -- ie:

```
 PortAddress = &HA25    ' etc
```

I'm not sure if the above DLL will let you specify other port addresses, it may not even be possible in modern windows to write to those ports directly (for system security reasons).  Typically you would have to resort to starting from the [Windows Driver Development Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - this is not always a practical approach.  It would be altogether better to see if your hardware manufacturer provides drivers already which you can import.

Comment: I'll try this on Monday. I'll tell what i find out. Thx