# Verify Encoding tags by Zebra printer RZ400

Tags: c#, zpl

The following is a C# function that sends ZPL command through serial port.
the ZPL Command Starts with ~RVE (which telling the printer to send RFID encoding success or failure results).

How can I receive the encoding result in the context of my code and check that the encoding process succeed?

```
    private void Print()
    {
        // Command to be sent to the printer
        string command = "~RVE^XA^RFw,H^FD033B2E3C9FD0803CE8000001^FS ^XZ";

        // Create a buffer with the command
        Byte[] buffer = new byte[command.Length];
        buffer = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
        // Use the CreateFile external func to connect to the LPT1 port
        SafeFileHandle printer = CreateFile("LPT1:", FileAccess.ReadWrite,
        0, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        // Aqui verifico se a impressora é válida
        if (printer.IsInvalid == true)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Open the filestream to the lpt1 port and send the command
        FileStream lpt1 = new FileStream(printer, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        Byte[] ResultBuffer = new byte[255];
        lpt1.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        // Close the FileStream connection
        lpt1.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you won't be able to retrieve result using LPT and CreateFile.
You need to use [bi-directional communication, using sockets.](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA140&actp=LIST)

Update:
There is a inpout32 library available, which allows two-way lpt port communications.

[Reading from Parallel Port using Inpout32.dll](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15020/Reading-from-Parallel-Port-using-Inpout32-dll)

[Converting Visual Basic parallel port app using inpout32.dll in to Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240520/converting-visual-basic-parallel-port-app-using-inpout32-dll-in-to-delphi)

[Download inpout32 binaries and sources](http://logix4u.net/inpout32_source_and_bins.zip)

Comment: Thanks for Quick replay, But my zebra (RZ 400) printer does not support network connection. is there is any way to retrieve result using LPT?

Comment: Updated answer. Not sure that this library will work, it is very outdated. Also you can try to read data the same way you write it - open LPT1 file and read from it.

Comment: The Zebra RZ400 has a serial port (you will need a null modem cable).  A ZebraNet Ethernet card can also be added.  Either of those options are good.  Zebra has a socket sample on their website: [Zebra Socket Sample](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SA140&actp=LIST_POPULAR)